# Unable to communicate with an element of my view with a layout, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, view, androidx

I am hoping that someone could please help me. I am creating an application using Kotlin. Mostly so far, so good, but I am having issues with one area.

The issue is with that 'distance.amountPicker.value' does not seem to be communicating with the layout. All of the other areas are working just fine i.e                 hikeName.text.toString(), etc, but I cannot get amountPicker to work.

I am not sure if the issue is with the import 'import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_hike.view.*', as these seems to be a different import than the rest, which use 'import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_hike.*'

If anyone could please guide me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Many thanks

Here is my code:
View:

```
package org.wit.hikingtrails.views.hike

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_hike.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_hike.view.*
import org.wit.hikingtrails.R
import org.wit.hikingtrails.models.HikeModel
import org.wit.hikingtrails.views.BaseView
import readImageFromPath

class HikeView : BaseView()
{

    lateinit var presenter: HikePresenter
    var hike = HikeModel()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hike)

        progressBar.max = 1000
        amountPicker.minValue = 1
        amountPicker.maxValue = 1000

        init(toolbarAdd)

        presenter = initPresenter (HikePresenter(this)) as HikePresenter

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
            presenter.doAddOrSave(
                hikeName.text.toString(),
                description.text.toString(),
                if(difficultyLevel.checkedRadioButtonId == R.id.Intermediate)
            "Intermediate" else "Hard",
                **distance.amountPicker.value**
            ) }

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener { presenter.doAddOrSave(hikeName.text.toString(), description.text.toString(), difficulty.text.toString(), distance.text.length) }

        chooseImage.setOnClickListener { presenter.doSelectImage() }

        hikeLocation.setOnClickListener { presenter.doSetLocation() }

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener { presenter.doDelete() }
    }

    override fun showHike(hike: HikeModel) {
        hikeName.setText(hike.name)
        description.setText(hike.description)
        distance.setText("Distance - "+hike.distance+"km")
        difficulty.setText("Difficulty Level - "+hike.difficultyLevel)
        hikeImage.setImageBitmap(readImageFromPath(this, hike.image.toString()))
        if (hike.image != null) {
            chooseImage.setText(R.string.change_hike_image)
        }
        btnAdd.setText(R.string.save_hike)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_hike, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
           if (hikeName.text.toString().isEmpty()) {

            R.id.item_cancel -> {
                presenter.doCancel()
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (data != null) {
            presenter.doActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        presenter.doCancel()
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.wit.hikingtrails.views.hike.HikeView">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:elevation="0dip"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarAdd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hikeName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:autofillHints=""
                    android:hint="@string/hint_hikeName"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_hikeDescription"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/chooseImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/button_addImage"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/hikeImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/hikeLocation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:text="@string/button_location"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hikeSubtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/donateTitle"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/donateTitle"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/hikeSubtitle"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/difficultyLevel"
                    android:layout_width="328dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/Hard"
                        android:layout_width="138dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="@string/hard" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/Intermediate"
                        android:layout_width="168dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="@string/intermediate" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/amountPicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="121dp"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/donateSubtitle"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="349dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/donateButton"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/donateSubtitle"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:indeterminate="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/distance"
                    android:layout_width="267dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/distance" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/difficulty"
                    android:layout_width="265dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/difficulty" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                    android:layout_width="375dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:text="@string/button_addHike"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/red"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:text="@string/button_deleteHike"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What's not working, the `distance.amountPicker.value` line with stars around it? In your layout, `distance` is a `TextView`, so it has no property called `amountPicker`, which is what that line is trying to access. Just use `amountPicker.value`. Also you really shouldn't be using those synthetic extensions anymore - they've been deprecated a long time, and won't build at all newer versions of Kotlin (which are required by some Jetpack library releases). Try to move to view binding instead! https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Comment: If you're just beginning, you may not want to waste time trying to get synthetics to work, because they are deprecated and are going to be incompatible with Kotlin 1.8+. This will effectively force you to remove synthetics at some point when the Jetpack libraries advance to Kotlin 1.8.

Comment: @cactustictacs thank you so much, that worked perfectly. I'm still getting to grips with Kotlin, so making some silly mistakes. I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: @Tenfour04, much appreciated for the advice. I actually had binding in here previously, but had been advised to go a new route. Might look at going back. Thank you

Comment: Yeah the synthetic extensions are really outdated at this point, you'll see them in old tutorials but you really don't want to use them now

Comment: View binding is very heavily recommended by Google as the current way to get view references. You can read about the deprecation of synthetics here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html